# Android Chat App that chat with all the users that are connected to the same public hotspot

Tags: android

I want to make an android app which on opening shows the list of all the nearby hotspot and user can connect to any of them. After that user can chat with all the other users who are connected to the same public hotspot through the app. A user can have a private chat or group chat.
First I tried to make my server using Nodejs and SocketIO, but I don't know how to fetch the list of all the connected user and have a private chat.
Is there is any other more efficient way to make an android app that works totally on the hotspot and does not require the Internet for it's working and is efficient?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Node.js+socket.io you need to save the user when it connects to Hotspot.
The app firstly communicate with the server after hotspot connection because the first one knows how to reach it (e.g. with an ip or a domain name).

After that the server need to save the current connection of the user (the opened websocket in your case) into a structure with other useful data, probably an user id.

After the registration of one user the server send to the client the list of connected peers on which the client app can start a communication (the previusly saved user ids)

When the client app choose someone the server create another structure for the chat and start to forward all messages from app client 1 to appclient 2.

For having group chat you need to handle this situation at server level where you have to register all the involved clients into a dedicated structure.

So to reassume, socket.io handle the communication and the server save the current state of client and chats (private or group) storing the connections of the clients in an appropriate way.

If you need to work only with the Hotspot you have two ways of doing this:

1 - Having a service on your phone that every time it will be connected to an hotspot send a broadcast message to the network. 
Every other client that is connected to the same hotspot receives that message and if it will have the same service running it will answer with another packet.
After that the starting client saves the address and can communicate with the other.
(The same thing can be done in an opposite way because the first client can send an alive broadcast message into the hotspot that signal all other clients that it is alive and present on the network, but it's better to not spam broadcast messages because they can congest the network)

2 - Do a network scan for every address of the hotspot

These two way have some security issues(e.g. not all the hotspot forward broadcast packets, no one knows if the connection is secure, ...). And remember that these two methods works only for local network.For internet communications there are other methods and approach that you need to follow and the complexity to create distribuited systems goes up.

There are a lot of examples e.g.

https://dev.to/medaymentn/creating-a-realtime-chat-app-with-android--nodejs-and-socketio-4o55

That you can follow to create a base for your application.

You have to add some modification in order to store all users that are connected to your server. At the top create a list of objects that have the unique id and store the socket of the joined client.
Create also another list of objects that represents your private chats. They will contain the ids of the two users.

In your server you need to create a method that return to you the ids of the clients. Something like this

```
socket.on('list-connected-peer',(params)=>{

//get all the ids from the list

socket.emit('response-list-connected-peer',listOfClientsIdJSON);

}
```

You have to call this method from the client and parse the json response to obtain all the ids you need.

You need also the creation of a method that add a new private chat to the private chat list. Using the same strategy as before you need:

```
socket.emit('create-private-chat',(params)=>{
//take the other id from the params
//create the chat object
//if you need notify the client that a private chat is created using emit
});
```

and finally you can do something like this

```
socket.on('private-message',(params)=>{

//get the two ids of the peers from the params,or the name of the chat item you create previously


otherSocket.emit('private-message',JSONmsg);
}
```

Remember to manage when an user disconnect from the server.

You could also see some WebRtc signaling server examples because it's doing something similar to your approach and a lot of implementation on the net use the same technology you are using (Node.js + Socket.io). Another good option could be using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Hope this helps or give you some hints.

Cheers.

Comment: I actually followed the same tutorial. But I was unable to implement the same to have one-to-one chatting with another user.Can you please help?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some snippets of code. Give more detail in your initial question about your problem for other users too.